# C++ dynamic memory allocation, using delete before new second time crash

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

i'm building a program to create a dynamic number of: char**.
The delete function in C++ is new to me so maybe i'm doing some basic error that I couldn't find an answer for in the internet.

The code works and delete successfully the arrays in the first time, but in the second time i got an:
"Heap corruption" error.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>

int addString(char*** mArr, char*** bArr, int& stringIndex);
int copyStrings(char*** mArr, char*** bArr, int stringIndex);
void deleteArr(char*** arr, int stringIndex);

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int stringChoice = 0/*USER CHOICE*/, stringIndex = 0;//HOW MANY STRINGS ARE CURRENTLY!
        int searchIndex = 0;//HELP THE SEARCH FUNCTIONS 6 AND 7.
        char** mArr = NULL;//MAIN ARRAY
        char** bArr = NULL;//BETA ARRAY TO AVOID LOSE OF DATA.

        cout << "Welecome to string menu, what do you want to do?" << endl;
        while (stringChoice != 8)
        {
            cout << "\n1.Add a string\n"
                << endl;
            cin >> stringChoice;
            switch (stringChoice)
            {
            case 1:
                addString(&mArr, &bArr, stringIndex);
                for (int j = 0; j < stringIndex; j++)
                    cout << mArr[j] << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

        int addString(char*** mArr, char*** bArr, int& stringIndex)
        {
            if (mArr != NULL)
            {
                copyStrings(mArr, bArr, stringIndex);//COPYING mArr TO bArr.
                deleteArr(mArr, stringIndex);//DELETE EVERYTHING FROM mArr. AVOIDING MEMORY LEAK.
            }
            stringIndex++;//ADDING A STRING TO THE ARRAY.
            *mArr = new char* [stringIndex];//ALLOCATING THE NEW SIZE AND CHECKING ALLOCATION.
            if (*mArr == NULL)
                return 0;
            if (*bArr != NULL)//IF SOMETHING WAS COPIED FROM mArr TO bArr BEFORE.
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < stringIndex - 1; ++i)//COPYING bArr TO THE MAIN ARRAY!
                {
                    *mArr[i] = new char(strlen(*bArr[i]) + 1);
                    if (*mArr[i] == NULL)
                        return 0;
                    else strcpy(*mArr[i], *bArr[i]);
                }
                deleteArr(bArr, stringIndex - 1);//DELETE EVERYTHING FROM bArr.
            }
            char checkLength[80];//BUUFER TO CHECK THE USER INPUT LENGTH.
            cout << "Please enter your string!" << endl;
            cin.ignore(1);//IGNORE BUFFER CHAR THAT WILL BE EQUAL TO - "ENTER".
            cin.getline(checkLength, 80);
            *mArr[stringIndex - 1] = new char[strlen(checkLength) + 1];//ALLOCATING THE LENGTH OF USER INPUT.
            if (*mArr[stringIndex - 1] == NULL)//                        ADDING 1 FOR THE NULL TERMINATOR.
                return 0;//CHECKING ALLOCATION.
            strcpy(*mArr[stringIndex - 1], checkLength);
            return 1;
        }

        int copyStrings(char*** mArr, char*** bArr, int stringIndex)
        {
            *bArr = new char* [stringIndex];//STRING INDEX IS HOW MUCH STRINGS WAS ADDED
            if (*bArr == NULL)
                return 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < stringIndex; ++i)
            {
                *bArr[i] = new char(strlen(*mArr[i]) + 1);
                if (*bArr[i] == NULL)
                    return 0;
                strcpy(*bArr[i], *mArr[i]);
            }
            return 1;
        }

        void deleteArr(char*** arr, int stringIndex)
        {
            cout << "string index value: " << stringIndex << endl;
            //  for (int i = 0; i < stringIndex; i++)
            //  {
            //      cout << i << endl;
            //      cout << *arr[i] << endl;
            //  }
            for (int i = 0; i < stringIndex; i++)
            {
                delete[] * arr[i];
                cout << "DELETE " << stringIndex << endl;
            }
            delete[] * arr;
        }
```

I'm trying to delete the arrays before using NEW again, to avoid memory leak.
In the first time it works as i said but the second time.....
There are a lot of printing references for me, so just ignore, it's just a small part of my first C++ project. 
Thanks!

Comment: `char***`. At that point, I give up. You should read up on `std::string`, references and other basic C++ techniques. If you even need `new`, it's in a constructor, and `delete` goes in a destructor, but 99% of the time there's already an existing class that does that for you.

Comment: You should use C++  and C++ structures instead of C-like abominations.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is one error

```
*bArr[i] = new char(strlen(*mArr[i]) + 1);
```

it should be

```
*bArr[i] = new char[strlen((*mArr)[i]) + 1];
```

Note the `*` and `[]` operator precedence is wrong as well as the type of brackets.
You make this error two times, `addString` and `copyString`.

Here's a similar error

```
            delete[] * arr[i];
```

should be

```
            delete[] (*arr)[i];
```

But actually this code could be written with one less level of pointers

```
    void deleteArr(char** arr, int stringIndex)
    {
        cout << "string index value: " << stringIndex << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringIndex; i++)
        {
            delete[] arr[i];
            cout << "DELETE " << stringIndex << endl;
        }
        delete[] arr;
    }
```

But there's a reason this kind of code is frowned upon.
Unless you've been told that you must write this code using these techniques give up now. `std::string` and `std::vector` are what you should be using for this task.

Comment: @DavidLivingston. There was nothing wrong with your deletes. You made two mistakes (in several places) `new char()` instead of `new char[]` and `*arr[]` instead of `(*arr)[]`.